# Snapshot testing with react-spring/react-motion

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme, react-motion, react-spring

I am trying to snapshot test my React components with Jest and Enzyme. Some components have the animation component (imported from `react-spring/react-motion`) in them, which renders a function as its child. This makes testing incredibly hard. I did quite a bit of research and came up with 3 ideas:

- Use Enzyme's `mount` to render everything, and snapshot test it. I found it impossible/ineffective for expensive components, and the snapshots produced are often really heavy (1MB - 2MB).
- Use Enzyme's `shallow` and snapshot test the component. Then find the animation component, render the children inside it using Enzyme's `renderProp()` and snapshot test them. This worked great until I found that `renderProp()` doesn't work nicely with `<StaggeredMotion />` for `react-motion` and `react-spring`. A workaround for this issue is explicitly call the function as `.prop('children')()`, then shallow the whole thing, but the code will then look messy and tough to read.
- Just use Enzyme's `shallow` and snapshot test the component. The rest are on the library's side.

**The question is:** Which one should I use? If none of these are good enough, what are the alternatives? Thanks in advance.

(If you need a code sample, I am more than happy to provide)

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @TimMG i decided to extract the part inside react-spring to a different component and test it. However i dont think we need to do this with the introduction of hooks

Comment: I followed your instructions and made a new component for the animation part, but my test still fails. This is probably because the new component is imported in the component I'm trying to test.

Comment: @TimMG If u open a new question, I will be more than happy to answer it

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220746/how-to-test-a-react-component-which-uses-react-spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got around the problems with testing components that use react-spring by mocking react-spring for Jest.

To do so, add this to your Jest config:

```
[...]
"moduleNameMapper": {
    "^react-spring(.*)$": "<rootDir>/jest/react-spring-mock.js"
},
```

The file `/jest/react-spring-mock.js` can look like this:

```
const React = require('react');

function renderPropsComponent(children) {
    return React.createElement('div', null, children()({}));
}

export function Spring(props) {
    return renderPropsComponent(props.children);
};

export function Trail(props) {
    return renderPropsComponent(props.children);
};

export function Transition(props) {
    return renderPropsComponent(props.children);
};

export function Keyframes(props) {
    return renderPropsComponent(props.children);
};

export function Parallax(props) {
    return renderPropsComponent(props.children);
};

export const animated = {
    div: (props) => {
        return React.createElement('div', null, props.children)
    },
};
```

Note: these mocks are focused on the render-props API of react-spring.
Also, this technique will results in ignoring everything that is normally generated by react-spring in your tests. (It will create a container `<div>` instead.)

Comment: Sounds like a good approach. Have you tried the new hook api?

Comment: I haven't yet, but I will. I guess they can be mocked in a similar manner. Something like `export const useSpring = () => [{}, () => {}];`